# request.COOKIES vs document.cookie in a django project

Tags: javascript, django, cookies

I am working on a Django project.I want to make a UI preference persist whether a user is logged in or logged out.

So cookies is the way i suppose. So i am confused whether `request.COOKIES`
in python and `document.cookie` in JS is the same thing.
I mean for getting and setting cookie value would it be same if i do from JS or a Django view.
I hope my question is clear. I am kind of new to subject of cookies.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`request.COOKIES` and `document.cookie` contain *the same set* of data; however, the ways of getting and setting cookie values are totally different.

`request.COOKIES` is a python dict for you to *read* cookie. For example, you have a cookie named "color" and its value is "blue", when you do `request.COOKIES['color']`, you get string "blue" back. You can't use `request.COOKIES` to set cookie, because these cookie values are sent by browser to django when browser makes request. To set cookie, you need to use `HttpResponse.set_cookie`. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie)]

`document.cookie`, on the other hand, is the cookies in the "raw" format, which is a string of semicolon separated name-value pairs. To read a specific cookie, you need to perform a search on that string to find the cookie you're looking for; to set a cookie, you need to call `document.cookie = "name=value;..."` [[ref](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)]. But most of the time, JavaScript libraries/frameworks have already done the dirty work for you, so to get/set cookie should be just a set of function calls.

Comment: +1 and just to stress, `request.COOKIES` is reading the cookies *server side* via python, while `document.cookie` is reading the cookies *client side*

Comment: Thanks @TimmyO'Mahony for the further explanation :)

Comment: I have one more doubt though. If i set a cookie through python, is it possible to see the cookie value in my browser , say through developer tools console as is done for document.cookie?

Comment: @SumeetDhariwal Yes, you can see it in devtools

Answer (score 1):

> request.COOKIES

returns

> A standard Python dictionary containing all cookies. Keys and values
>   are strings.

and`document.cookie` returns a string

I think its more easy to iterate over an dictionary and get all the cookies than parse the string returned by javascript

Comment: My issue is that for setting the cookie i dont want to send the response back which is the case in django. Thats why i was thinking of using javascript if both things work the same way.

Comment: Well if you do not want to send the response back, You should use JavaScript

Comment: Is there any way to set request.COOKIES in javascript or django template ?

Comment: You're welcome,in your view you can send a variable that takes the request.COOKIES value  and then you are going to be able to use it in the django template:D